# Losing data by using the function unlist

Tags: r

I have a simple but strange problem.

indices.list is a list, containing 118,771 Elements(integers or numeric). By applying the function unlist I lose about 500 elements.

Look at the following code:

```
> indices <- unlist(indices.list, use.names = FALSE)
> 
> length(indices.list)
[1] 118771
> length(indices)
[1] 118248
```

How is that Possible?? I checked if indices.list contains any NA. But it does not:

```
> any(is.na(indices.list) == TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

data.set.merged is a dataframe containing more than 200,000 rows. When I use the vector indices (which apparently has the length 118,248) in order to get a subset of data.set.merged, I get a dataframe with 118,771 rows!?? That's so strange!

```
data.set.merged.2 <- data.set.merged[indices, ]
> nrow(data.set.2)
[1] 118771
```

Any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: Could you please put more information about `indices` and `indices.list`, e.g., `class(indicies)`, `str(indicies)`, etc.

Comment: I'd really like to see `dput(indices.list)` =)

Comment: Ok, I looked at dput(indices.list) and found some elements integer(0). This could be the problem. how can I test how many elements are equal to intrger(0)?? And what exactly does integer(0) mean? I created indices.integer by using the grep function.

Comment: `integer(0)` is simply a zero length vector of type integer. You can find such things by checking their length, which will be 0. They will also be dropped bu unlist, as well as NULL. But you're going to have to be much more forthcoming with relevant, useful (reproducible!) information if you expect good answers.

Answer (score 10):

Well, for your first mystery, the likely explanation is that some elements of `indices.list` are `NULL`, which means they will disappear when you use `unlist`:

```
unlist(list(a = 1,b = "test",c = 2,d = NULL, e = 5))
     a      b      c      e 
   "1" "test"    "2"    "5"
```